# Facing an issue for querying error as "HSQL Database : Unexpected token: END in statement"

Tags: java, jira, active-objects

I have created an activeobject query as below:

```
ao.find(IP.class, Query.select().where("user=? AND start>=? AND end<=?",u,datefieldl,datefieldl))
```

but it gives me below error:

> There was a SQL exception thrown by the Active Objects library:
>   Database: - name:HSQL Database Engine - version:1.8.0 - minor
>   version:8 - major version:1 Driver: - name:HSQL Database Engine Driver
>   - version:1.8.0 java.sql.SQLException: Unexpected token: END in statement [SELECT * FROM PUBLIC.AO_0371A8_IP WHERE user=? AND start>=?
>   AND end<=?]

create entity stuff is as below:

```
 IP pi = ao.executeInTransaction(new TransactionCallback() // (1)            
    {   
         @Override
         public IP doInTransaction()
         {
            logger.info("before ao.create");
            IP pi = ao.create(enclass);
                                ....

            pi.save();                              
            return pi;          
         }
    });
```

My entity is looks as below:

```
@Table("IP")
@Preload
    public interface IP extends Entity {

    @Accessor("issues")
    String getIssues();

@Mutator("issues")
void setIssues(String issues);

@Accessor("planStartTime")
Date getPlanStartTime();

@Mutator("planStartTime")
void setPlanStartTime(Date planStartTime);

@Accessor("planEndTime")
Date getPlanEndTime();

@Mutator("planEndTime")
void setPlanEndTime(Date planEndTime);

@Accessor("user")
String getUser();

@Mutator("user")
void setUser(String user);
}
```

any idea?

Comment: if i remove last parameter - "end<=?" then it works. But i need to use that third parameter also as i need result of query like all records which are fall under start <== "datefield1" >= end.

Answer (score 0):

> Unexpected token: END in statement

Take a look at your conditions:

```
"user=? AND start>=? AND end<=?"
```

`END` is actually an SQL keyword (following the line of `IF` and `BEGIN`). Change that to, for example:

```
"user=? AND sessionStartTime>=? AND sessionFinishTime<=?"
```

The problem here is that when the final SQL query is generated, it has an invalid syntax. That's why you're getting the exception.

Comment: I hve updated start and end with - "planStartTime" and "planEndtime" at all related places. Now, My entity as below: @Preload
public interface IP extends Entity {
 

    Date getPlanStartTime();
  
    void setPlanStartTime(Date planStartTime);
    
    Date getPlanEndTime();
  
    void setPlanEndTime(Date planEndTime);
    
    String getUser();
  
    void setUser(String user);    
    
}
When execute the query then it gives me columns not found error - "Column not found: PLANSTARTTIME in statement [SELECT * FROM PUBLIC.AO_0371A8_IP WHERE user=? AND planStartTime>=? AND planEndTime<=?]"

Comment: @Dhaval how are you annotating those columns? Also, did you regenerate the schema or update the column names yourself? The database table must be outdated by having the previous column names (generated by your provider or by you) and that's why it doesn't find the new ones.

Comment: I have just renamed entity interface's properties - "getStart()" to "getPlanStartTime()", "setStart()" to "setPlanTime()" and same for "end". and related changes in rest service where i have created entity and used. Actually, i have created this table just through below stuff:

Comment: I have updated original question to include create query stuff. and retrieved object has properties as follow - '@XmlAttribute
    private Date planStartTime;
    
    @XmlAttribute
    private Date planEndTime;'

Comment: i have updated entity field by adding annotation attributes - accessor and mutator as shown in updated original comment above. Actually, save and "retrieve all" methods are working fine. but this query gives me error as " Column not found: PLANSTARTTIME in statement [SELECT * FROM PUBLIC.AO_0371A8_IP WHERE user=? AND planStartTime>=? AND planEndTime<=?]" . I have not given capital "PLANSTARTTIME" though in error it shows capital.. might some case sensitive issues or what could cause ?

Comment: @Dhaval Something is amiss... if saving and retrieving work fine then the problem is introduced when you specify the columns yourself. Did you check the actual table in the database? I mean, whatever database you use (MySQL, Postgres, ...), did you check the actual table and its columns? I don't see issues in your code.